# gzip.NewReader() returns nil when a type Reader is given as input

Tags: python, go, io, null, gzip

I've come across a problem while uncompressing a stream of bytes that are previously compressed. Basically, I'm trying to create a Reader using the function `bytes.NewReader()` and then to unzip the stream by using `gzip.NewReader()` function. At last, I'd like to return the real values in either string or byte format.

I know `gzip.NewReader` requires `io.Reader` as an input, however, as far as I know, type `Reader` implements the interface `io.Reader`. I assume this should not cause any errors but I wonder what might be the problem in this case. I'd really appreciate if you help me out with this!

In case you wonder what this piece of text is,

> "amZzRUR2NHVtcVpiZHNROHJiTTNYeGdUSndGTlVDZC9jaElSK1lXcFlJOD0="

it's a sample input sent from my client python script. It compresses by using gzip, does encryption by using AES128 and finally encodes in base64, in this order.

The client code:

```
import time
import json
import requests
import random
import gzip
import base64

from Crypto.Cipher import AES

baseurl = 'http://0.0.0.0:80'
key = 'TfvY7I358yospfWKcoviZizOShpm5hyH'
iv = 'mb13KcoviZizvYhp'

MODE = AES.MODE_CFB
BLOCK_SIZE = 16
SEGMENT_SIZE = 128

def http_post(url, data):
    print('Going to make a request to {} with the following data: {}'.format(url, data))
    r = requests.post(url,
                  data=data,
                  headers={'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                           'Connection': 'keep-alive'}, )
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print('Server returned unexpected response code {}, and content: {}'.format(r.status_code, r.content))
        return False
    else:
        data = r.json()
        return data


def post_sample_data(key, iv):
    fake_device_id = "MB88"
    Load_VA_Total_Mean = random.randint(1000, 100000)
    print('Data that should come back: {}'.format(Load_VA_Total_Mean))
    data = {'i': fake_device_id, 'p': [
    {'d': [54.3, 0, 99, 49.35, 3, 99, 51.533, 1, 98, 28964, 7348, 43590, Load_VA_Total_Mean, 10350, 55200, 49.7],
     't': time.time(), 'dt': 'p'}]}
    url = baseurl + '/realtimedata'
    encryption_key_reference = 1
    payload = '{}\n{}'.format(convert_pack(data, key, iv), encryption_key_reference)
    return http_post(url, payload)


def convert_pack(inputdict, key, iv):
    jsonpayload = json.dumps(inputdict)  # encode dict to json string
    gzippayload = gzip.compress(jsonpayload.encode('utf-8'))  # compress with gzip
    encryptedpayload = base64.b64encode(encrypt(key, iv, message))
    encoded = base64.b64encode(encryptedpayload)
    print('encoded: {}'.format(encoded))

    return str(encoded, encoding='utf-8')


def _pad_string(value):
    length = len(value)
    pad_size = BLOCK_SIZE - (length % BLOCK_SIZE)
    return value.ljust(length + pad_size, '\x00')


def encrypt(key, iv, plaintext):
    aes = AES.new(key, MODE, iv, segment_size=SEGMENT_SIZE)
    plaintext = _pad_string(plaintext)
    encrypted_text = aes.encrypt(plaintext)
    return encrypted_text


post_sample_data(key, iv)
```

The server code:

```
package main

import (
"crypto/aes"
"crypto/cipher"
"crypto/rand"
"encoding/base64"
"fmt"
"io"
"compress/gzip"
"io/ioutil"
"bytes"
)

func main() {
    receivedText := "amZzRUR2NHVtcVpiZHNROHJiTTNYeGdUSndGTlVDZC9jaElSK1lXcFlJOD0="
    fmt.Println("encrypted + encoded + gzipped: ", originalText)
    key := []byte("TfvY7I358yospfWKcoviZizOShpm5hyH")

    text := decrypt(key, originalText)
    fmt.Println("decrypted: ", string(text))
    reader := bytes.NewReader(text)
    gzReader, err1 := gzip.NewReader(reader)
    fmt.Println(gzReader)

    if err1 != nil {
        fmt.Println("error1")
    }

    content, err2 := ioutil.ReadAll(gzReader)

    if err2 != nil {
        fmt.Println("error2")
    }

    fmt.Println(string(content))
}

func decrypt(key []byte, cryptoText string) []byte {
    ciphertext, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(cryptoText)
    fmt.Println("decoded: ", string(ciphertext))
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    iv := []byte("mb13KcoviZizvYhp")
    stream := cipher.NewCFBDecrypter(block, iv)
    stream.XORKeyStream(ciphertext, ciphertext)

    return ciphertext
}
```

The output:

```
<nil>
error1
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x288 pc=0x10a9167]

goroutine 1 [running]:
io/ioutil.readAll.func1(0xc420037dd0)
    /usr/local/go/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go:30 +0x119
panic(0x10c4580, 0x1154d00)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:489 +0x2cf
compress/gzip.(*Reader).Read(0x0, 0xc420092000, 0x200, 0x200, 0x1024ade, 0xc400000008, 0xc4200120c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/compress/gzip/gunzip.go:247 +0x37
bytes.(*Buffer).ReadFrom(0xc420037d28, 0x11451a0, 0x0, 0xc420092000, 0x0, 0x200)
    /usr/local/go/src/bytes/buffer.go:179 +0x160
io/ioutil.readAll(0x11451a0, 0x0, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go:33 +0x150
io/ioutil.ReadAll(0x11451a0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x7, 0x0, 0x0, 0x20)
    /usr/local/go/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go:42 +0x3e
main.main()
    /Users/bkaankuguoglu/Desktop/Go-dev/tool-backend/tester.go:43 
+0x404
exit status 2
```

Comment: you show that it returns an error (which should be checked first) so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Print the actual error message and it will tell you exactly why it failed. "some text here" is not a vaild input to gzip.

Comment: @JimB I edited my question now, thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @Art Yes, I know. There are multiple steps in the process, but I just wanted to cut the parts that I encode and encrypt the bytes. I figured the problem is most likely due to gzip. Here is a proper gzip:
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\xcd1ZY\x02\xff%\x8e\xb1\x0e\xc3@\x08C\x7f\x051\xa3\x13w@\x0e:v\xef\x17T\xd9\xb2t\xcb\x90-\xca\xbf\xd7i\'xX\xb69\xf9\xc3\x0f\xe2\xd73\x93\x85x\x07\xbcO\xde\xee\x11\xdeLH\x85\xaa\x84\xbc\x9a\x85\x90\xfd)z\x0b\xc3\xde\x81)4\xb2\x16\x17\x9a\xe6\x00\xb7(\x98F,P\xbbZ\x00"\x86\xea/d\xaeh9\x10\xdf\xbdJ\xd3F\xb7\x96\x05\xfb\xc4}\xbb\x05\xfcp\xad\xd7\x17\x19o\xdd\xe7\x98\x00\x00\x00'

Comment: @bkaankuguoglu It would help immensely if the question you ask actually contains the actual question you want to ask instead of a different question. As it is (after fixing the problems that makes the question not even compile), the answer to the question as asked right now is: your input is not valid gzip. Now, that string you pasted into the comment might be an encoding of a valid gzip string (at least the header is there). How do you input it into the program?

Comment: @bkaankuguoglu Here is a fixed test program with a fixed up string (since the one in the comment was messed up by formatting): https://play.golang.org/p/UUI7nz06gs   Works For Me.

Comment: The nil error is a red herring, you're getting an error from `gzip.NewReader` then you continue trying to process, which definitely won't work. Once you get an error you should print *the actual error message*, then stop trying to use the results of a failed operation.

Comment: Ok. Now, as edited, it is pretty clear that after the first round of base64 decoding the input what comes out is another base64 encoded string. This doesn't smell right.

Comment: @Art After comparing my input text sent from my client script and some other gzip outputs, I assume that my input may not be a valid gzip stream.

Comment: Yay. Now that you posted the python script, I see that my guess was right. The output is base64 encoded twice.

Comment: And after decrypting that what comes out is a string that contains "The answer is no". Considering that the python script doesn't do anything with `gzippayload`, and encrypts something called `message` (that doesn't appear anywhere else in the script), that's not too surprising.

Comment: @Art Yeah, I deleted that extra line but now new error occurred. I'll post the final version after I fixed those errors. Thanks!

Comment: @Art I wasn't using that variable in any part of the script. I used that to verify if my encrypt/decrypt functions work.

Comment: I bet that is not the full Python script, instead the actual Python script contained code copy-pasted from some pycrypto tutorial that uses the string "The answer is no" as their test string.

Comment: Btw. Stop converting things to/from strings and byte arrays all the time. The beauty of interfaces in Go and especially `io.Reader` is composition. Your code should look something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/M9jTbAdWja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the "content" produced by the reader you pass to `gz.NewReader()` is not a valid gzip stream (data). If `gzip.NewReader()` returns a non-`nil` error (as it does in your case), the returned `gzReader` may be `nil` (and it usually is).

If you pass a valid gzip stream to `gzip.NewReader()`, the returned `gzReader` will not be `nil`, and decoding will succeed.

For example the gzip encoded form of the text `"hello"` is:

```
[31 139 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 203 72 205 201 201 7 0 134 166 16 54 5 0 0 0]
```

Using this as the input:

```
data := []byte{31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    255, 203, 72, 205, 201, 201, 7, 0, 134, 166, 16, 54, 5, 0, 0, 0}
reader := bytes.NewReader(data)
// The rest is unchanged
```

It works, and the output is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wvjlodJOWq)):

```
&{[31 139 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 203 72 205 201 201 7 0 134 166 16 54 5 0 0 0] 0 -1}
&{{ [] 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC  255} 0x10440260 0x10462000 0 0 [31 139 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] <nil> true}
hello
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my program, firstly, I gzip the input string, then encrypt using aes256 and finally encode the text in base64. I've checked the last two steps that I encrypt and encode my date, it seems like it works fine without the gzip step. What is a valid gzip stream? Something like this?

\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\xcd1ZY\x02\xff%\x8e\xb1...

Comment: @bkaankuguoglu I don't know the gzip spec by heart, I can't tell just from the bytes. If it's valid, the `gzip` package should accept it. If it doesn't accept it, it's most likely it's not valid. In your example you should reverse the steps: first base64 decode, then aes256 decode, and then you can pass the result to gzip decoding.

Comment: I added the full version of my script. I'm doing the steps in the order you described.